I cannot see the Access Log records of my NodeJS application on the panel
I have a domain and subdomain. I'm running a NodeJS application on port 5656 in a folder of my subdomain. I cannot see HTTP methods such as GET POST that I created with NodeJS in my panel. I am using CloudPanel.
I opened this file and added location /api/ proxy_pass. but there was no change.
I want all operations performed on my NodeJS application to be added to log records.
root@ubuntuserver:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# sudo nano api.mywebsite.org.conf

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/api.mywebsite.org.key;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/api.mywebsite.org.crt;
  server_name api.mywebsite.org;
  root /home/mywebsite-api/htdocs/api.mywebsite.org;

  access_log /home/mywebsite-api/logs/nginx/access.log main;
  error_log /home/mywebsite-api/logs/nginx/error.log;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }



  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }



# I added this but it didn't work
location /api/ {  # Node.js uygulamanıza yönlendirmek istediğiniz yol
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5656;  # My NodeJS app port
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}






  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|o>
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}


server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name api.mywebsite.org;
  root /home/mywebsite-api/htdocs/api.mywebsite.org;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:18003;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
error_log=/home/mywebsite-api/logs/php/error.log;
memory_limit=4G;
max_execution_time=600;
max_input_time=600;
max_input_vars=10000;
post_max_size=512M;
upload_max_filesize=512M;
date.timezone=Europe/Istanbul;
display_errors=off;";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}




